# Using regexp to match pattern not in img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to do an online chatting application, its **sending emoji** ability like this:

[image]

So I use an div whose contentEditable is true as input area. And all of the message would be saved in database in this way:

`"Hello, Cathy<img src="/public/face/Mazes_Mini_017.png"><img src="/public/face/Mazes_Mini_017.png">"`

All of these above works well, but at that time I want to do a **search** ability, highlighting the key word I search, I met a problem when I want to use **string.replace** method to replace `myKeyWord` with `<span class='highlight'>myKeyWord<span>`, but it would **match** some characters in `<img>` tag...

eg. `<img src="/public/face/Mazes_Mini_017.png">112233test112233</img>123test123`

keyword is **test**

expected result is:
<img src="test.png">112233test112233</img>123**test**123

So I really want to use regExp to matched some characters **not in** a specify tag like `<img>`, I have tried a lot but no one worked...

Comment: You can use [negative assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match only the keyword which is **not** inside `<img>` tags.

Comment: Just want to point out there shouldn't be `</img>` and you shouldn't put text "inside" `<img>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an example](https://regex101.com/r/hG2pQ8/1)

You could try this: `(?<!<\/)test(?![^<]*<\/img>)`

Comment: But I think using `test(?![^<]*<\/img>)` is enough, because `test` would never appear as `<test>` tag